# Google Chrome positioning issue

Tags: css

I have a problem positioning some text in google chrome, I am trying to position 
"Get Directions" and "Contact" side by side. This works fine in IE,Firefox and Opera but not Chrome. I know I should probably use floats but does anyone have any idea why isn't this working correctly?

(CSS)

```
    #main_container2{

    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
    left: 0%;
    top:0%;
    width:950px;
    height:985px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:36pt;



    }
```

(HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='green_machine.css'>
<title> test</title>

</head>


<body bgcolor="black">

<div id="main_container2">

<p></p>
<font style="position:absolute;top:5%;left:6%;">Get Directions</font><p></p>
<font style="position:relative;top:5%;left:56%;">Contact</font><br>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use:

```
<font style="position:absolute;top:5%;left:6%;">Get Directions</font><p></p>
<font style="position:relative;top:5%;left:56%;">Contact</font><br>
```

First element `position: absolute` and second element `position: relative`

Just set the both to `absolute` or `relative`

PS

I would have made it into a `ul` and `li`'s

And either use `float` or display `inline`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need the left and top arguments on the main-container div, by default a positioned element is anchored top left.

To fix your problem though, you should try switching the second font tags position to absolute. Since the parent has a position (defined or not) the children's position will be within the parents container. Since you are trying to put them side by side, you should use position absolute on both elements.

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I need to go back and learn css positioning :(